# Source in mapping is not migrating properly through fcat in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am facing some issue while migrating the work flow to another repository using fcat. Actually what I did is firstly I changed the field lenght like 40 to 100 in source to till target after we did a test run in Dev repository it is fine in. After we are migrating same work flow to UAT repository through fcat but after migrating to UAT the field lenght is still 40 only. Can any one give some suggestion on how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: hmm, looks like its not migrating properly. I am just curious - what is `fcat`? Could you please check if workflow is checked out in UAT or not? If its not, please see if you are using admin user, if yes, please delete the mapping completely and remigratee.

Comment: Yeah updated mapping not getting migrated, so I just added description in mapping and re migrated. Now it's fine.